# Read n test cases from file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to use Python for a few sample programming competition questions, but I've been stumped on file reading.

I'm reading from stdin, the first line is the number of test cases that follow, each subsequent line contains two integers that I need to process. E.g.

```
3
4 -10
0 5
6 20
2
0 -1
20 10
etc...
```

I've found a C++ solution that looks like this:

```
int main()
{
 int runs,a,b ;
 cin >> runs ;
 while(runs--)
 {
  cin >> a >> b ;
  long long ret = solve(a,b) ;
  cout << ret << endl ;
 }
 return 0 ;
}
```

The closest I've come up with in Python is:

```
t = int(raw_input())
answer = 0
while t :
    n, m = map(int, raw_input().split())
    answer = solve(n,m)
print answer
```

I've seen similar questions on Stack Overflow but I'm still having a tricky time wrapping my head around the Python way to do this.

Comment: since you are not assigning anything to `t` ,you are in infinite loop ..right there..

Comment: Other than the infinite loop, what is the problem with the python code you have written there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use raw_input you can use fileinput instead:

```
import fileinput

input = fileinput.input()
for line in input:
    for j in range(int(line)):
        solve(*[int(i) for i in input.next().split()])
```

or with sys.stdin

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    for j in range(int(line)):
        solve(*[int(i) for i in sys.stdin.next().split()])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
3
4 -10
0 5
6 20
2
0 -1
20 10
```

You would do it like this.

```
num_of_testcases = int(raw_input()) # this corresponds to 3 and 2
for each in range(number_of_testcases):
    x, y = map(int, raw_input().split()) # this would give the pair of numbers
```

In the contests, usually, you will have the total number of test cases. You have not mentioned it here. It is taken upfront

```
total_test_cases = int(raw_input())
```

and then you iterate the above input gathering routine over the `total_test_cases` If the total test cases is not present, then you can iterate over while True and then cancel at EOF.

```
for tc in range(total_test_cases):
   num_of_testcases = int(raw_input()) # this corresponds to 3 and 2
   for each in range(number_of_testcases):
       x, y = map(int, raw_input().split()) # this would give the pair of numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import sys
for l in sys.stdin.readlines()[1:]:
    a,b = map(int,l.split())
    #now process your test cases
```

Also according to your input file description there should only be one set of test cases.Like so:

```
3
4 -10
0 5
4 20
```